# What is cs_main? Why is it called cs_main?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, validation, c++

What is `cs_main`? Why is it called `cs_main`?

This question was asked during the May 12th 2021 [Bitcoin Core PR review club](https://bitcoincore.reviews/21767) hosted by John Newbery on a Carl Dong PR to de-globalize `ChainstateManager`.

(The lock on `cs_main` was discussed in this StackExchange [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/what-is-the-function-of-lockcs-main).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is `cs_main`?

`cs_main` is a recursive mutex which is used to ensure that validation is carried out in an atomic way. It guards access to validation specific variables (such as `CChainState` and `CNode`) or mempool variables (in `net_processing`). The lock of `cs_main` is in [validation.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/validation.cpp).

> Why is it called `cs_main`?

`cs_main` was the mutex ("critical section") that protected data in Satoshi's original main.cpp file. (main.cpp was entirely removed in [PR 9260](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/9260) in December 2016.) In theory `cs_main` could be renamed today as main.cpp has since been refactored into smaller files but every time you rename something in a header file, everyone needs to recompile any file that includes that header.

A long-term goal is to separate out those different bits of data that are protected by `cs_main`, so that eventually `cs_main` only protects the data inside validation.

These were answered by John Newbery and other participants of the May 12th 2021 [Bitcoin Core PR review club](https://bitcoincore.reviews/21767).